# Generate a new string with two strings

Tags: string

I'm writing a super simple chat app and I'm going to store chat history between two users A and B as plain text files. Each user has a unique ID so I think I can concatenate two users' IDs to make a new string as the file name. Then if one user login to my app and wants to retrieve his conversation history with another user, he has both IDs to get the file name.

The problem is the order of the two IDs when doing concatenation, it seems I have to sort them first so it's always the same order no matter user A or user B wants to get the chat file name.

Is there some other way so I don't need to sort those two strings first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple comparison for this since only two IDs are involved.

```
string GetId(string a, string b) {
    // Use some separator that's not part of the IDs or you risk mixing up file names from a different pair of User IDs.
    string sep = ":";
    if (a < b) {
        return a + sep + b;  
    } else {
        return b + sep + a;
    }
}
```

Comment: Or (if non numeric characteras can be a problem) zero-pad user ids to, at least, the maximum digits single valid usere id can have. But separator is easier and more efficient, of course ;-)